# Set-Cookies in .NET 5 REST API

Tags: c#, rest, cookies, .net-5, angular11

I have problem with setting cookies from .NET 5 REST API . Front-end is built on Angular 11 , both project are on different domains . At first I was creating and appending cookies to response from Controller so Set-Cookie was presented in http response but wasn't saved in browser . We tested it on localhost and on already deployed website and it doesn't gets saved in either way . Then I tried to make it as a service and now cookies doesn't even gets sent with response , but when I debug it goes in a Cookie Service class and creates cookie and appends it to Http response . I don't get what is happening or why . Do I need to save cookies from in Angular ? or Set-Cookies should save it automatically in browser.

Can someone explain , if Set-Cookie header is present on response why it might not get saved ?
I have tried marking cookies with HttpOnly , Secure , SameSite - None (since they are on different domains ) and vise versa but it simply doesn't works.

Would appreciate any help , Thanks .

Comment: Most likely this is caused by proliferation of third party cookies blocking in recent browsers. Get some old Chrome version from say 2018 and see if it works in that.

Read up in more details: https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie

Lastly, I recommend you revisit your design, in most cases with ng apps and .net backend there is rarely a need to communicate data via cookies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.